# Predicate not calling in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

```
solve([("ab","abab"), ("b","a"), ("aba","b"), ("aa","a")], Solution)
```

Answer has been delivered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWI-Prolog 7.x changed the default value of the `double_quotes` flag from `codes` to `string`. This is apparently what's causing the problem you describe. If you add, at the top of the source file with the code you posted, the following directive:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).
```

You should get:

```
?- solve([("ab","abab"), ("b","a"), ("aba","b"), ("aa","a")], Solution).
Solution = [4, 4, 2, 1] ;
Solution = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4] ;
Solution = [4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1] ;
Solution = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2|...] ;
Solution = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4|...] ;
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how i can use this code and combine it with a dfs or an IDA* search?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666468/pcp-semi-decideable-with-prolog
Here is the dfs/ida* search I have to use. Your solution helped me already, thank you very much!

Comment: Did it! Still have an idea how to use graph search IDA* or DFS in combination to this code?

Comment: Only looked briefly to the problem itself but assuming that you ca formulate it as a *state-space search problem*, the Logtalk distribution includes a `searching` example that implements a framework to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: @A.A. put some effort into figuring your way into the problem and then you can ask a more specific question that you can post separately. As it stands, your question is quite broad. If you were to post it in that state, it would likely get down-voted and probably voted for closure.